# 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates

I keep getting that exception because of changing when I try to change the UI to my wpf application

```
private delegate void MyFunctionDelegate2(double t1, double t2, double t3);

public void translate(double tx, double ty, double tz)
{
    Transform3DGroup transform = new Transform3DGroup();
    TranslateTransform3D t = new TranslateTransform3D(tx, ty, tz);
    transform.Children.Add(t);
    if (!Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        var objj = new MyFunctionDelegate2(translate);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(objj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not pass the three arguments to your MyFunctionDelegate2 in the BeginInvoke call. It should look like this:

```
private delegate void MyFunctionDelegate2(double t1, double t2, double t3);

public void translate(double tx, double ty, double tz)
{
    if (!Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        var t = new MyFunctionDelegate2(translate);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(t, tx, ty, tz);
    }
    else
    {
        var transform = new Transform3DGroup();
        var t = new TranslateTransform3D(tx, ty, tz);
        transform.Children.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Or simpler, without the delegate declaration:

```
public void translate(double tx, double ty, double tz)
{
    if (!Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            new Action(() => translate(tx, ty, tz)));
    }
    else
    {
        Transform3DGroup transform = new Transform3DGroup();
        TranslateTransform3D t = new TranslateTransform3D(tx, ty, tz);
        transform.Children.Add(t);
    }
}
```